# double plus (+) sign in SAS code, what does that mean?

Tags: sas

came across the following code and struggle to understand what do the double plus (++) signs do.

```
do _point= 1 by 1 until ( EOF );
  set LOOKUPDATA (keep=KEY) end = EOF;

  if hashtable2.find() ne 0 then _n_ = 0;
  _n_ ++ 1 ;
  hashtable2.replace();
  hashtable1.add();
end;
```

Comment: It means "I am a C programer.".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called the Sum statement. The syntax is

```
variable+expression
```

In your example expression is

```
+1
```

Yes is could have been written without the extra +

Equivalent to this

```
retain variable 0;
variable=sum(variable,expression);
```

Comment: Thanks, this also answers a question which occured to me yesterday.

Comment: @MichaelKersten which part of the answer?  I basically copied the online documentation for the sum statement.

Comment: I didn't know that

    variable+Expression

leads to an implizit retain of variable.